# Expected class name before { token

Tags: c++, inheritance

Here are the two header files.Child and parent.Can anyone explain why this error occures?

Thanks in advance

SampleApplication.h:

```
#ifndef SAMPLEAPPLICATION_H_
#define SAMPLEAPPLICATION_H_

#include "ns3/CcnModule.h"
#include "ns3/CCN_Name.h"
#include <string>

class CcnModule;

class SampleApplication : public ns3::Application
{

   public:
    ns3::Ptr<CcnModule> ccnm;


    static ns3::TypeId GetTypeId(void);
    virtual ns3::TypeId GetInstanceTypeId (void) const;
    SampleApplication();
    SampleApplication(ns3::Ptr<CcnModule> ccnm);
    virtual ~SampleApplication();
    char* data;
    int length;
    ns3::Ptr<CCN_Name> dataName;
    void SendInterest(ns3::Ptr<CCN_Name> n);

    void SendData(ns3::Ptr<CCN_Name> data, char* buff, int bufflen);
    virtual void InterestReceived(ns3::Ptr<CCN_Name> ccnn);
    virtual void DataArrived(ns3::Ptr<CCN_Name> data, char* buff, int bufflen);

    void AnnounceName(ns3::Ptr<CCN_Name> n);

    virtual void DoDispose();
    virtual void DoInitialize();
};

#endif
```

Receiver.h:

```
#ifndef RECEIVER_H_
#define RECEIVER_H_


#include "ns3/CcnModule.h"
#include "ns3/CCN_Name.h"
#include <string>
#include <vector>
#include "ns3/SampleApplication.h"


class CcnModule;
//class SampleApplication;

class Receiver : SampleApplication
{

   public:

    static ns3::TypeId GetTypeId(void);
    virtual ns3::TypeId GetInstanceTypeId (void) const;
    Receiver(ns3::Ptr<CcnModule> ccnm);

    virtual ~Receiver();

    void SendInterest(ns3::Ptr<CCN_Name> n);

    virtual void DataArrived(ns3::Ptr<CCN_Name> data, char* buff, int bufflen);
};

#endif
```

Comment: This error occurs at which line?

Comment: class Receiver : SampleApplication
{

Here ,as if SampleApplication is not a class.

Comment: This basically means that `SampleApplication` is not being recognized as a type. Which means that there is somthing wrong with your inclusion of header files. Either you have a circular dependency (and thus it is not visible at the point you are using it) or it is in a nested namespace and not visible. Can you reduce this to a small compilable example that reproduces the problem.

Comment: If `SampleApplication` is not in the ns3 `namespace` (as stated in comments below) then why does the include look like this? `#include "ns3/SampleApplication.h"` (note the ns3 there).

Comment: @LokiAstari I up-voted that comment, but at the same time I wonder how the preprocessor would not puke on a missing `ns3/SampleApplication.h` header file if that isn't where it is (unless the OP is storing it there, which would not be the wisest move). The fact that the OP is forward-declaring `CcnModule` even though what appears to be the proper `ns3/CcnModule.h` header include is right above leads me to believe something even more fundamental is the issue.

Comment: @WhozCraig: Assuming `ns3` is some module that is being used. It may potentially contain its own `SampleApplication` class. The user `Range` may be implementing his own version of `SampleApplication` in his own namespace. Or something like that. There is not enough information here to answer the question (and thus we can just speculate in the comments). We need a compilable example to proceed further.

Comment: @LokiAstari if it *compiled* the OP wouldn't be here. =P I'm still hung up on why the OP is forward declaring classes *without* a namespace resolution that should be in what appears to be the ns3 namespace (like CcnModule).

Comment: @WhozCraig: What I am guessing. Is that there is a header file `ns3/SampleApplication.h` but it contains stuff for the ns3 package. Our OP `Range` has his own header file `SampleApplication.h` that contains his definition. This is the file he should be including not the other one. As a complete guess.

Answer (score 0):

I am not familiar with library you are using but I am guessing it is the NS-3 Discrete Event Network Simulator and from a cursory glance at the API I would expect to see the include

```
#include "ns3/application.h"
```

In your SampleApplication.h file.

It may well be that it is already pulled in by some of those other includes in your implementation but at first glance it appears to be missing.